# I don't understand how to implement this gem

Tags: ruby

I'm very new to ruby, working on my first project and one thing I'm trying to do is convert HSL colour values to RGB. I found a gem to do this called 'Color'which I've installed and read over the documentation, however I can't figure out how to actually implement the code.

What I have so far is values stored in 'h', 's', and 'l' as an integer between 0 and 360 for h and a decimal between 0 and 100 representing a percentage for s and l.

The documentation says, if I understand correctly that I need to first use the [#initialize](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/halostatue/color/Color/HSL#initialize-instance_method) constructor using my variables for the values, however when I copy the syntax provided and try to write them in, it doesn't work. I'm not sure how I'm supposed to be setting this up and the last hour of googling hasn't given any clear answers. The # also confuses me, whenever I type it it just makes everything on that line following it a comment.

It's also not clear to me if this stores the s and l values as decimals between 0 and 1, which I understand is needed for their [#to_rgb](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/halostatue/color/Color/HSL#to_rgb-instance_method) method. I can divide them by 100 before they're initialized, but the documentation for that step suggests that they should be from 0 to 100.

I know these are very rudementary questions, but I'm new to this and still trying to wrap my head around all of the syntax. I appreciate any time put into responses, thank you!

EDIT: Don't really know what it's asking me to do but here's some code. I don't understand where I'm supposed to be putting initilalize or if that # is supposed to be there since it makes comments in ruby. When I put it in nothing happens since it's a comment. I try to put a variable name ahead of it like "hsl_init#initialize(...)" and I get:

*undefined local variable or method `hsl_init' for main:Object (NameError)*

```
hsl_init#initialize(h, s, l, radix1 = 360.0, radix2 = 100.0, &block)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: I'm not sure what part I can add, it's quite a lot of code to take certain inputs from a site and generate the values, which are then stored on h, s, and l. I'm more or less just trying to figure out what the gem documentation is telling me to do next with those values.

Comment: You say that the code you wrote "doesn't work" but you included neither the code nor a description of the manner in which it doesn't work. This would be a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've updated it with what I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem's documentation is not friendly for people who are very new to Ruby. However, the tests and documentation are quite complete for someone who knows how to read it.

Here is an example drawn from [the tests](https://github.com/halostatue/color/blob/master/test/):

```ruby
require 'color'

# make some instances of the different classes
hsl_teal = Color::HSL.new(180, 50, 50)
rgb_pink = Color::RGB.new(255, 127, 127)

# convert between HSL/RGB
rgb_teal = hsl_teal.to_rgb
hsl_pink = rgb_pink.to_hsl

# or display as text
puts rgb_teal.html       # prints HTML-suitable RGB hex values
puts hsl_white.css_rgba  # prints CSS-suitable RGBA values
```

### Explanation

#### The `#` sign in documentation

The `#` sign is the comment character in actual Ruby code, yes, but it has another meaning outside of the actual code -- that is, in places such as documentation and Stack Overflow answers.

When someone writes `SomeClass#some_method`, you can read it as "the method named `some_method` on an *instance* of class `SomeClass`". Another phrase that people use is to call `some_method` an *instance method* on `SomeClass`.

Likewise, when documentation talks about `#my_method`, it refers to an instance method called `my_method`. Usually it's clear which class you're talking about - if you're reading documentation for `Color::HSL`, then `#to_rgb` probably means `Color::HS#to_rgb`.

#### The "constructor" method `#initialize`

The `#initialize` method is a little bit special in that you normally don't call it directly. Instead, you call `.new` (the *class method* called `new`), and that allocates a new object then runs `#initialize` on that new object.

This isn't technically a constructor but an initializer, however the distinction often doesn't make a difference.

#### Decimals for saturation and lightness

According to the documentation, the default radix for saturation and lightness (the S and L of HSL) is 100. The Color gem will divide by the radix, so an S value of 50 with the default radix of 100 is half-saturated. You would pass a different radix (such as 1.0) if you wanted to use a different scale.

Comment: Thank you that's so much easier to understand. Every time I googled it I found things about class methods and instance methods,  I thought I somehow had to create a class to apply everything to. It's super clear now,  I appreciate it!